# OOM on devices with smaller RAM

Tags: android, json

I have two json files in the assets folder. The problem is that on devices with smaller memory I get the out of memory error. What can I do to solve this? I have the following code:

Variables to store json

```
private static JSONObject one;
private static JSONObject two;
```

Method to set variables

```
public static void setJSON(Context context){
    try {
         one = new JSONObject(loadJSON(context,"one.json"));
         two = new JSONObject(loadJSON(context,"two.json"));
    } catch (JSONException e) {
         e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Method to load json

```
private static String loadJSON(Context context, String filename){
    try {
        InputStream is = context.getAssets().open(filename);
        int size = is.available();
        byte[] buffer = new byte[size];
        is.read(buffer);
        is.close();
        String json = new String(buffer, "UTF-8");
        return json;
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        return null;
    }
}
```

Comment: The main problem is you are trying this in main thread use asynctask for json parsing

Answer (score 0):

There are a couple of ideas which might help here (and it would have helped to show a JSON file snippet)

A) How big are your JSON files? JSON processing is memory heavy, as you need to have RAM for the parser *and* the objects it creates in memory. Can you shrink the JSONs?

B) Can you load them one at a time? process, and free?

C) If all else fails, try splitting them into bunches of several objects, then load.

D) All in all, JSON is a terrible form of serialization. If you can use Java serialization instead, you'll be looking at a LOT less memory.

Comment: The files are together 4.5MB. I cannot change the files. I need both at the same time and pre-loaded, because I don't want to parse the json when the user is clicking on a button. That would increase the loading times.

Answer (score 0):

Do not use JSON, but convert your data to normal SQLite database and have it prepopulated in your APK file in `assets` folder. Then on first run you install it to app folder (you can use [this tool](https://github.com/jgilfelt/android-sqlite-asset-helper)) and then, finally use normal database and just get data you need at that moment, without need of loading whole JSON

Comment: A server is generating json files and the app needs to synchronize the local files with the server files.

Comment: then use `pagination` approach perhaps to have smaller JSON to deal with